# Android sending data to server with soap

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I want to get data from user through edittext in android and send it to server with the help of **soap request** i.e. in xml format,can somebody please help me reply a.s.a.p.???

Comment: Post webservice request structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the request in xml format as shown in the xml below. Modify the same according to your needs.

Example. (using KSOAP2 library)

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://service.medal.org/", "GetPosts");

        PropertyInfo getpostreq = new PropertyInfo();
        getpostreq.name="GetPostsReq";
        getpostreq.type=String.class;
        getpostreq.setValue("<GetPostsReq>"
        +"<sessionId>"+sessionid+"</sessionId>"
        +"<postedAfter>"+5+"</postedAfter>"
        +"<postedBefore>"+20+"</postedBefore>"
        +"<radius>10</radius>"
        +"<location>"
        +"<latitude>"+lati+"</latitude>"
        +"<longitude>"+longi+"</longitude>"
        +"</location>"
        +"<postedBy>all</postedBy>"
        +"</GetPostsReq>");

        request.addProperty(getpostreq);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelop.setOutputSoapObject(reques
```

Comment: FYI, This is by using `KSoap2` library.

Comment: @Shubham did you try the above?

Comment: I'm trying to do it like this String envelope="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"+
      "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"+xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"+
        "<soap:Body>"+
          "<GetItems xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"+
            "<first>%s</first>"+
            "<last>%s</last>"+
            "<getAll>%s</getAll>"+
          "</Items>"+
        "</soap:Body>"+
      "</soap:Envelope>";
     String requestEnvelope=String.format(envelope, f,l, "true");

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: first and last are the string that i'm taking from user through edittext

Comment: that's the server part to be handled. You need to receive the soap request and process the same on the server side. String s= edittext.getText().toString(). use the string s accordingly.